# How to parse Nested tag with same name using XMLpullparser in android

Tags: android, xmlpullparser

I want to parse title and link tag only in item section with XMLpullparser. how do i parse it with ignoring previous title and link tag?

```
<channel>
 <title>AAA</title>
 <link>linkone</link>
 <item>
  <title>BBB</title>
  <link>link2</link>
 </item>
</channel>
```

The parser which i am using currently is following. How do ignore starting title and link tag?

```
try {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

        FileInputStream fis = ctx.openFileInput("StackSites.xml");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

        xpp.setInput(reader);

        int eventtype = xpp.getEventType();
        while (eventtype != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
            String tagname = xpp.getName();

            switch (eventtype){
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if(tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
                        curStackSite = new StackSite();
                    }
                    break;

                case  XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    curText = xpp.getText();
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if(tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
                        stackSites.add(curStackSite);
                    }
                    if(tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("title")){
                        curStackSite.setName(curText);
                    }
                    if(tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("link")){
                        curStackSite.setLink(curText);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            eventtype = xpp.next();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know wheather its right way to do it, but what i did is inside  case XmlPullParser.START_TAG: if it found item tag , ive set counter is equal to 1. and in case XmlPullParser.END_TAG: if counter != 0, then only it adds value to object .this method works. if anybody knows more accurate way please post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is one library available to parse xml response to POJO class.
https://github.com/stanfy/gson-xml

By using this library, you do not need to do manual parsing. You need to create POJO class according to your xml.

For given xml, you need to create two POJO classes

Channel.java

```
public class Channel {
    Item item;
}
```

Item.java

```
public class Item {
    String title;
    String link;
}
```

Now you can parse your xml like below

```
public void parseXml(Strng xml){
    XmlParserCreator parserCreator = new XmlParserCreator() {
            @Override
            public XmlPullParser createParser() {
                try {
                    return   XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newPullParser();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
        }
    };

    GsonXml gsonXml = new GsonXmlBuilder().setXmlParserCreator(parserCreator).create();

    Channel channel = gsonXml.fromXml(xml, Channel.class);
    Log.v("temp", "Title : " + channel.item.title);
}
```